# How to get fixedresponseconfig on boto3 to work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to create an integration between EC2-ALB and Lambda functions and in a part of my code I am trying to use the method:

modify_listener() documentation available here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.modify_listener

in that part I am using the DefaultAction: FixedResponseConfig where I am trying to display a simple hello world on html. the way this gets triggered in the code is, if my target group is unhealthy display the fixed response permissions have been setup everything looks fine because when I run the function I get a successful message but when I ask for the application from my okta portal I don't get that response (hello world) I get a normal 503 service temporary unavailable.

How can I direct that fixed response to the frontend of the app when is not working? the purpose of this is to display a maintenance page when the target group is down.

Thanks for the responses please feel free to make any question.

Comment: How did it go with the issue?

Comment: @Marcin Hey sorry for not responding this it went well after using method modify_rule() due that this changes in real time.

So I can display the fixed response correctly, now I am trying to either through JSON or HTML write an instruction that is capable to redirect the fixed response to an HTML page the syntax is as follows: 

Actions=[
'Type':'fixed-response'
 'TargetGroupArn':'<whatever-your-target-group-arn-is>'
 'FixedResponseConfig':{
    'MessageBody': 'HTML or JSON instuction that redirects to a file or folder of files in the AWS file manager from lambda (SS added)'

}
]

Comment: @Marcin Please let me know if that makes sense to you.

Comment: New question for the new issue would be better. Also if my answer was helpful to the original issue asked, it's acceptance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize ALB's error messages through fixed response. Instead you should consider two options:

- use CloudFront in front of your ALB to setup [Custom Error Page for Specific HTTP Status Codes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html)
- use Route53 [DNS failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html) when your ALB becomes unhealthy.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for your response !
See that is the weird thing if you go to the ALB > Listener (in my case port 443) >  and modify the rule to if (trying to access X path in my web app) then throw a fixed response works! but this happens from the front end only I have not been able to make it work automatically but currently trying with a different method instead of:

modify_listener() I am changing to modify_rule() method possibly there is the problem

Comment: @Quintabug598 Yes, if the rule matches, then fix response will be shown. But there is no failover in ALB to show fix response automatically when there is no healthy targets.

Comment: Well it looks like it, after implementing the modify_rule() method it didn't worked throwing an error occured (InvalidLoadBalancerAction) when calling the modify_rule operation: You cannot specify 'target group ARN' for actions of type 'fixed-response'

Does this mean that doing this through Lambda is a waste of time?

Comment: @Quintabug598 I'm not sure what do you want to do with lambda? Set fixed response text message?

Comment: What I want to do is establish a lambda function that is capable of detecting the health of my target group and if is unhealthy return an error page. that error page should be capable of showing in HTML format with some CSS.